# Trouble passing boost::shared_ptr<> into NewObject()

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, swig, shared-ptr

Perhaps I'm being too ambitious here, but I'm trying to pass a shared_ptr back to Java through an Exception like so.

I am able to catch the Exception in java, but when I try to access any methods in the ManagementProcessor object itself I get a SIGSEGV.  If I use new ManagementProcessorPtr() to send in an empty one I get the correct behavior (I throw a different exception).

Any insights?

Thanks!

-Chip

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<ManagementProcessor> ManagementProcessorPtr;

%include "boost_shared_ptr.i"
%shared_ptr(ManagementProcessor);
%typemap(javabase) Exception "java.lang.RuntimeException";
%typemap(javabase) AuthenticationExceptionManagementProcessor "NS/Exception";

%exception {
try {
  $action
}
catch (AuthenticationException<ManagementProcessor> & e ) {
  jclass eclass = jenv->FindClass("NS/AuthenticationExceptionManagementProcessor");
  if ( eclass ) {
    jobject excep = 0;
    jmethodID jid;

    jstring message =  jenv->NewStringUTF(e.getMessage().c_str());
    jstring file =  jenv->NewStringUTF(e.getFileName().c_str());

    ManagementProcessorPtr* realm = new ManagementProcessorPtr(e.getRealm());
    jlong jrealm;
    *(ManagementProcessorPtr **)&jrealm = realm;

    jid = jenv->GetMethodID(eclass, "<init>",
        "("
        "LNS/ManagementProcessor;"
        "J"
        "Ljava/lang/String;"
        "Ljava/lang/String;"
        "J)V");
    if (jid) {
        excep = jenv->NewObject(eclass, jid,
            jrealm,
            e.getApiErrNum(),
            message,
            file,
            e.getLineNum());
        if (excep)  {
            jenv->Throw((__jthrowable*) excep);
        }
    }
  }
```

Client code:

```
} catch (AuthenticationExceptionManagementProcessor e) {
        java.lang.System.err.println(e);
        ManagementProcessor mp = e.getRealm();
        java.lang.System.err.println("got mp");
        java.lang.System.out.println(mp.getUUID());
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And of course the right answer is that first I have to create the Java ManagementProcessor object with the ctor that takes a CPtr:

```
jclass mpclass = jenv->FindClass("NS/ManagementProcessor");
jobject jmp = 0;
jmethodID mpid;
ManagementProcessorPtr *realm = new ManagementProcessorPtr(e.getRealm());
jlong jrealm;
*(ManagementProcessorPtr **)&jrealm = realm;
mpid = jenv->GetMethodID(mpclass, "<init>", "(JZ)V");
jmp = jenv->NewObject(mpclass, mpid, jrealm, true);
```

...

```
        excep = jenv->NewObject(eclass, jid,
            jmp,
            e.getApiErrNum(),
            message,
            file,
            e.getLineNum());
```

Answer (score 1):

a `boost::shared_ptr` is a c++ *class*.  what makes you think that it is the same as a `ManagementProcessorPtr*`?

Comment: I know they're not the same.  What should I pass into the constructor?  I see the SWIG generated code uses things of the form  *(VolumePtr **)&jresult = new VolumePtr((const VolumePtr &)result);
all over the place.